# does MVC enumerate results *after* a return statement somehow? 

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I have code that looks like this:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult CustomerSearch(string firstName ...
 {
 ...
 try 
 {
   var results = from t in db.Customers... 
   var custResults = results.Select(c=> new string[] { ... });
   return this.Json(custResults );
 }    
 catch (TimeoutException exc1)
 { 
    return this.Json(new {error = "Search failed (timeout)"});   
 }
 catch (System.Exception exc)
 { ... }
}
```

I test this by setting the timeout on the sql call to something small (5s). The exception is certainly happening, I can see it in my logs and the `protected override void OnException` event is firing. But the catch for the `TimeoutException` or `Exception` never gets hit. I suspect there's something about how MVC works that I'm not understanding.

The peculiar thing is that if I put a breakpoint on the `return this.Json(custResults);` I can pass that line with no problem. But if I put a `ToList()` on the `.Select(..)` then the TimeoutException will be thrown. How can MVC enumerate a result set after a return statement has been executed?

Comment: Where is the try that the catch is associated with?

Comment: I susspect that your catch is throwing an error, you could try add break points to verify this.

Comment: Assuming the TRY has been omited for brevity I think this might be a deyled execution issue.  The linq statement will not actually be run until it is used.  To test the catch simply put Throw new Exection("test"); at the top of the method and see if it gets caught.

Comment: Assuming that the try is around the action, this should work. I'd confirm to see if the JsonResult is getting passed successfully -- my guess is something is causing the error object to get masked.

Comment: @hitlikeahammer: right, forgot the try. You were right that it was a delayed execution issue, but it seems like the linq statement would be used on the `return this.Json(..)` line. But it wasn't. The catch was only hit after I added a ToList() at the end of the select. This seems odd to me.

Comment: To clarify: adding a ToList() at the end of the Select causes the catch block to be hit in the event of a timeout. Without the ToList() the catch block is never hit and it falls to the OnException method to handle the error. What I don't understand is how I can put a breakpoint on the "return this.Json(custResults );" line, pass that line and then get the exception after the pointer has left the CustomerSearch method (if I don't have a ToList()). It seems like the MVC engine would have to enumerate the results to be able to return something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Json` is likely a lazy method, in that it does not enumerate the result set given. Instead it wraps the result set in another enumerator. This means that until the MVC needs the results the SQL is never executed. Given that your functions do not perform the enumeration but MVC does, this causes the exception to happen where you cannot wrap it in a try/catch block.

As you mentioned in your post added a ToList() will cause the enumeration of the set and storage into a location, causing the exception to happen where you expect it to.

Comment: how could I determine if it is a Lazy method? I don't see anything in its inheritance that points to that.

Comment: @jcollum: I would personally examine the type of the result. It returns a JsonResult object wrapped around the supplied object. JsonResult simply stores the object (as an object), so it is not performing any analysis at this point. This means that the ActionResult is being handled at some point in the program. (BTW I open Microsoft.Web.Mvc.dll in IL disassembler, but sometimes you can  figure it out from the documentation).

Answer (score 0):

The Select() call will create a deferred (lazy) enumeration

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx:

> This method is implemented by using deferred execution. The immediate return value is an object that stores all the information that is required to perform the action. The query represented by this method is not executed until the object is enumerated either by calling its GetEnumerator method directly or by using foreach in Visual C# or For Each in Visual Basic.

Doing ToList() or ToArray() will create a non-deferred collection out of it